# In App Purchase issue after purchase

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, async-await

I found an odd behaviour with IAP on WP8 SL, once the purchase has been done from the IAP task the code following the await request does not run at all, it somehow skip it, I've a try-catch but no exception are thrown at all. I would appreciate if you give it a look. Let me know if you need more informations.

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listing2 = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
        var noads = listing2.ProductListings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value.ProductId == "RemoveAds" && p.Value.ProductType == ProductType.Durable);
        try
        {
            await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(noads.Value.ProductId, false);
//nothing happen from here
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }  
}
```

Comment: have put the break point or waiting for messagebox to show message ?

Comment: I have put a breakpoint on the messagebox but it just skip it after the purchase request. As for waiting for the messagebox I don't see what you mean by that.